# why i can't display my records in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, records

I have records in my database but I can't display them. Can someone check my codes, please. I'm just an amateur web developer. Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
$groups=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY id ASC");
$g_res=mysql_affected_rows();
if($g_res>0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($groups))
{
    $g_id=$row['id'];
    $g_name=$row['g_name'];

    $members=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE group='$g_id'");
    $m_res=mysql_affected_rows();
    if($m_res>0)
    {
        while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($members))
        {
            $m_id=$row2['id'];
            $m_name=$row2['m_name'];
            $m_email=$row2['m_email'];
            echo "<tr><td>$m_name<br/>($g_name)</td><td>$m_email</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<tr><td colspan=2>Nothing to display</td></tr>";
    }
}
}
else
{
echo "<tr><td colspan=2>Error</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

With this code I get the `else` result which is `Error`. If I remove `WHERE group='$g_id'` from the query, all of my records are displayed randomly, but I'd like to show my records (members) by group.

Comment: **warning** your code maybe vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Please do not use deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to get the error from a SQL query; add this into your else statement somehow so you can see the error

Comment: also, you will get better performance with a join.

Comment: Don't forget to fix: `echo "<tr><td>".$m_name."<br/>(".$g_name.")</td><td>".$m_email."</td></tr>";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) like `group` with backticks

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE `group` = '$g_id'
                            ^-----^-------------here
```

You can also spare the inner loop when you join your data like this

```
select g.id as gid, g.g_name, m.id as mid, m.m_name, m.m_email
from groups g
inner join members m on g.id = m.group
order by g.id asc
```

This is easier and will increase performance since you don't need to execute a lot of queries but just one.

Also please [don't use mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). 
They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
Learn about **Prepared Statements** instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for a quick overview how to do it and why it is so important.

Comment: i didn't know that 'group' is a reserved words in MySQL. thank u man for pointing that out. this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$members=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `group` = '".$g_id."');
```

or simply

```
$members=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `group` = '$g_id'");
```

Comment: Don't forget the apostraphes in your second example there around $g_id

Comment: Since it is an integer value we dont need to put apostaphes for that I thnk

Comment: Can't hurt though in case it isn't integer, id generally is integer but there doesn't appear to be anything in his code that forces it to be

Comment: Ok @AlexColeman I have added that also...thanku for the valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate your variables.
Try this:

```
$members=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `group`='".$g_id."'");
```

And

`echo "<tr><td>".$m_name."<br/>(".$g_name.")</td><td>".$m_email."</td></tr>";`